# git copy commit from a branch to another

Tags: git

what's complicated in that :
I want to copy the last commit from "dev" branch to "master" branch.

I am doing this

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick a6b9463bec0a5240f6e945fbf4951c932751f28d
```

and I get an error :

```
git cherry-pick a6b9463bec0a5240f6e945fbf4951c932751f28d
error: could not apply a6b9463... releasing v1.00
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

`git status` gives

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# You are currently cherry-picking.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      index.html
#   both modified:      js/boardDims.js
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   config.xml.orig
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I don't see why it's that complicated to copy a comit to another branch.
Can you give me command to copy this commit to my master branch ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try resolving the conflicts? (hint: `git mergetool`)

Comment: yes but I don't understand what is popping out : there are 3 files...

Comment: Don't look at it as 3 files, it's basically one file in 3 states (commit1, commit2, after resolving)

Comment: Thanks @Tim I get it now, the middle file is the final one (in meld)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the correct command and it's telling you that you have conflicted changes in `index.html` and `js/boardDims.js`. Resolve the conflicts with a diff tool, run `git add` on each of them and finally `git commit` to commit the merge.

Answer (score 1):

When you cherry pick, you're copying a "change", not the files themselves. When copying a change, the process is very similar to creating a patch of the last commit from the dev branch and applying that patch on the master branch. If the patch fails, which it did, Git will tell you to resolve the conflict, which it did.

While most of the time cherry picking is used to grab a single commit, [it can be used to grab a series of commits](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

To resolve the conflicts, you can use `git mergetool`

[Here's a visual explanation of cherry picking](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html). (Scroll down to the slide show at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

It's only "complicated" because there are merge conflicts when you cherrypick the commit. This is normal behaviour if commits from different branches changed the same line in common file.

You can learn something about solving merge conflicts [here](http://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts)